# Make vscode understand p5js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I recently started P5JS, and I use VSCode as an editor.

VSCode doesn't know P5JS, because it's a library I guess, and makes all the wrong autocompletes.

Is there a way to import the P5JS languagefiles into VSCode, because it's a real pain.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try downloading the typescript definitions from NPM https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1339#issuecomment-438066393 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as **Intellisense for P5.js in Visual Studio Code** is concerned, there is currently no official build of p5.js typescript definition files, hence it cannot be done with `npm install`. I have attached a link to a zip file (as stack overflow doesn't support file attachment):

https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/795689/p5.d.zip

After download, put them in your project directory somewhere and add a reference to them in your sketch.js file.

E.g:

< reference path="./p5.global-mode.d.ts" / >

After that you will be able to get autocomplete & docs:

[image]

Comment: How did you build these doc files?

Comment: You can get these files from DefinitelyTyped now, there's an NPM module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/p5

Answer (score 4):

I used a P5.js extension and it seems to have done the trick. You will need to download the live server extension in the image:

[image]

You will also need to create a folder and then need to type this into the command palette:

"create p5.js project"

Then you select your folder and then you should see this:

[image]

You then select sketch.js for JavaScript and you may also edit the html code if you would like.

Answer (score 3):

I prepared a ready-to-use [zip-file](https://breaksome.tech/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/P5JS_Project_Template_For_VSCode.zip) with the newest version of P5JS and the typescript definitions referenced already. Download > Unpack > Open With Code > Done.

I also [blogged](https://breaksome.tech/p5js-editor-how-to-set-up-visual-studio-code/) about this solution in more depth, if you want to know more.

*Edit December 2021: Updated the ready-to-use [zip-file](https://breaksome.tech/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/P5JS_Project_Template_For_VSCode.zip) to the newest version pf P5JS.*

Comment: Is there a way to set the reference path without having to put a special comment in my sketch.js file? Can it be put in .vscode preferences file or something?

Comment: Where did you get the p5 typescript definitions? Is it from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/p5 perhaps?

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING!!! Thank you SO much, it worked perfectly and thank you for your blog! I'm using my own file structure for my p5.js folders, so I don't want to use the p5 extensions. Thanks for helping an old newbie to VS Code!

Answer (score 2):

Open the extensions manager in the side bar of VSCode, and type in 'p5'. You will find several options to install.

Either click on the icon pointed by an arrow or use keyboard shortcut as follows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> 'Extensions: Install extensions`

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66791042/2158546, p5.vscode is an extension that includes autocompletion.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into vscode extensions and type in "p5js", one of the extensions is called "p5.vscode". Install that extension, that should allow you to create a p5js template.

If you want a test canvas you can also install the p5canvas extension which can be used by clicking on the "p5canvas" on the bottom blue bar while in a p5js project.

I know this question is a bit old, but I still wanted to communicate what has worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I compare two different files, one generated with the P5.js extension(with working Intellisense) and one existing **P5.vscode** directory(no working Intellisense) and the only difference was the following file **jsconfig.json** so I added it to the second directory and it worked but the **P5.vscode** extension needs to be installed.
The file contained this:

{
"include": [
"*.js",
"libraries/*.js",
"c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\samplavigne.p5-vscode-1.2.11\p5types\global.d.ts"
]
}